# React-Native -> Couldn't change style using state

Tags: react-native

I've got a problem with my app. I'm trying to change style in my child component using states but unfortunately i dont get any results. I tried evrythig i know, but i dont know what is going on and why styles aren't changing at all

Here is parent :

```
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        number: 1,
        cords: [

        ],
        choosenCords: [

        ],
        style: {flex:1,flexDirection:'row',backgroundColor:'red'}
    };
} 
<View style={{ marginTop: 3 }}>
  <ListItem style={this.state.style} test={this.state.test} title={item.timestamp} context={item.longtitude + " " + item.latitude} click={this.getData.bind(this, item.longtitude, item.latitude, item.timestamp)} />
</View>

getData = async(x, y, z) => {

    let tempTab = []
        tempTab.push(x)
        tempTab.push(y)
        tempTab.push(z)
        const changeTest = this.state.test * (-1)
        await this.setState({
            choosenCords: [...this.state.choosenCords, tempTab],
            style: {flex:1,flexDirection:'row',backgroundColor:'blue'}
        })
}
```

}
This fragment of code represent changing style onPress. "choosenCords" are changing, but "style" don't.

Here is child:

```
class ListItem extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        test:this.props.test
    };
}

render() {
    return (
        <View style={this.props.style}>
            <Image
                source={require('../Images/gps.png')}
                style={{ borderWidth: 3, borderColor: '#7887AB', borderRadius: 50, marginLeft: 15, marginTop: 10 }}
            />
            <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: "column", marginBottom: 15, marginLeft: 10 }}>
                <Text style={{ marginLeft: 10, fontSize: 16 }}>
                    {
                        "Timestamp: " + this.props.title
                    }
                </Text>
                <Text style={{ marginLeft: 15, fontSize: 15 }}>
                    {
                        "Cords:" + this.props.context
                    }
                </Text>
            </View>
            <TouchableHighlight
                underlayColor={'transparent'}
                onPress={
                    this.props.click
                }>
                <Image
                    source={
                        require('../Images/check.png')
                    }
                    style={{ marginRight: 20 }}
                />
            </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
    );

}
```

Could someone help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

You have to do like this:

```
const customStyle= this.state.test ? styles.custom_1: styles.custom_2

return <View
      style={[ styles.anyStyle, customStyle]} 
    />;
```

Define your custom style variable, set it based on `state`, then use it as an array for your element.

Comment: It still doesn't change color. In console.log i see that parent state is changing but color stay the same

Comment: It's changing color before i add child do parent component. I need to change it color when it is already in there

Comment: Missing the spread operator.
return <View
      style={[ ...styles.anyStyle, ...customStyle]} 
    />;

Answer (score 0):

The child component does not automatically update when the state of the parent component changes. You'll need to update the state of the child component manually when the parent sends new props.

```
//in child component
componentDidUpdate(previousProps, previousState){
   if(previousProps.style !== this.props.style){
       //update child state here
       this.setState({style: this.props.style})
   }
}
```

Now instead of using "style={this.props.style}" in the child, use "style={this.state.style}"

Comment: Using `PureComponent` for the child component is often a better way to handle props changes !

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because when you update your state, child component will not update automatically. you will get new updated value in **componentWillReceiveProps()** method.

your **ListItem** class will be like below:

```
  class ListItem extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        test:this.props.test,
        style:'' // take style into your state
    };
}
componentWillMount(){
       this.setState({style: this.props.style}) //set style 
}
componentWillReceiveProps(newProps){
     //called when you update style
   if(newProps.style !== this.props.style){
       this.setState({style: newProps.style})
   }
}
render() {
    return (
        <View style={this.state.style}> //set style for views from state
           // add your views here
        </View>
    );
}
}
```